# Print multiple copies of "Print Selection" Excel 2007

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2007, printing

I have a user who is trying to print only a certain set of cells in Excel 2007, but she needs to print 2 copies of the selection.

Using the print dialog, she selects `Selection` under `Print What` and sets `Number of copies` to 2.

[image: Print Dialog]

The printer then only prints a single copy of the selection.  No second page, no blank page, nothing.

Any ideas to get the printer to print a second copy?

Details:

- Windows 7 (Up to date)
- Microsoft Excel 2007 (Up to date)
- Local Printer

Comment: @pnuts Yes, it is up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the following suggestion [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/unable-to-print-multiple-copies-from-excel-also/de2e6a1b-0be5-49f6-8bf5-798286d91a0b):

This problem is caused by Mopier Mode being enabled by default. The idea of Mopier Mode is to minimise computer and network traffic by sending only 1 copy to a printer equiped with suitable internal memory. That stored copy is then used to produce the multiple copies. Most HP Laserjets do not have suitable internal memory and so only the one copy sent by the computer gets printed. To disable Mopier Mode:

Click Start
Click Devices and Printers
Right click your Laserjet Printer
Select Printer Properties
Click the Device Settings Tab
Scroll down to the bottom
If necessary, expand Installable Options
Click on Mopier Mode
Select Disable in the selection box that appears
Click Apply
You will now get multiple copies.